# Trying to get csv file from Github, working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, ubuntu-18.04

```
$path_to_file = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_daily_reports/".date_format($date,"m-d-Y").".csv";

$csvData = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}..
```

This is the code I'm using for retrieving COVID-19 data from a Github CSV. The array is later processed in a table, so I can show the data for a specific region. All is working fine on Xampp in localhost, but when I go live, it doesn't work. I checked the php.ini file and `allow_url_fopen = On`. Why is this happening? I'm supposing that is an error on my server config.

Comment: define *it doesn't work*? have you checked error log, enable error reporting.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone the table is empty with the same code I'm using on localhost (where it shows corerctly all the data). It's like when it is running on the server, it couldn't retrieve the CSV file from GitHub.